# How to increase mdb consumers in weblogic?

Tags: jms, weblogic-10.x, ejb-2.x

Have a problem with my mdb where I have observed newer messages getting consumed before the older ones and suspect the round robin load balancing policy to be the culprit. I can see weblogic console has 16 consumers, but sometimes if 1st consumer is occupied 17th message remains in queue and 18th is picked up for processing. Planning to solve this by increasing the number of consumers as my maximum volume is 45 messages in short span and each message may take from 5 to 110 minutes to process.

Comment: What is the question? Have you looked at unit of ordering with JMS? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13727/uoo.htm#JMSPG389

Comment: Hi. thanks for the response. Even though my problem is with unit consumption, I am looking for a long term solution. Also I used customized work manager to resolve the issue.. Thanks again.